# magento installation 2.4.2 404 whoops my bad

Tags: magento2, php-7, localhost

```
    php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost:8054/magento241/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="someoneid.p@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="Admin@123" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="Asia/Kolkata" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200
Starting Magento installation:
```

all went well as per the doc mentioned here https://www.simicart.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-localhost/. but i got error like : [image]

php v 7.3
xamp
os windows 10

tried :
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

but still it is same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Magento 2.4.2 the root www server document folder for Magento must be `magento2/pub/`.

Make sure you configure your web server to use this folder as the document root.

For example for Apache:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/magento2/pub/
```

*Note that Windows is not a supported operating system for Magento 2.*

Answer (score 0):

Create a symlink for pub/media and pub/static. In your magneto root folder run the following commands -

```
 ln -s pub/static
 ln -s pub/media
```

Now run the following commands -

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reset
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Comment: all good my bad. I am using windows 10. I need it for my development.